# Exit part of a script in Spyder

Tags: python, csv, exit, spyder

I am working in a simple task of appending and adding an extra column to multiple CSV files.

The following code works perfectly in Python prompt shell:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

data_path = "C:/Users/mmorenozam/Documents/Python Scripts/peptidetestivory/"
outfile_path = "C:/Users/mmorenozam/Documents/Python Scripts/peptidetestivory/alldata.csv"

filewriter = csv.writer(open(outfile_path,'wb'))
file_counter = 0
for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_path,'*.csv')):
        with open(input_file,'rU') as csv_file:
                filereader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                name,ext = os.path.splitext(input_file)
                ident = name[-29:-17]
                for i, row in enumerate(filereader):
                    row.append(ident)
                    filewriter.writerow(row)            
        file_counter += 1
```

However, when I run this code using Spyder, in order to have the desired .csv file, I have to add

```
exit()
```

or type in the IPython console "%reset".

Is there a better way to finish this part of the script? because the following parts of my code work with the .csv file generated in this part, and using the options above is annoying